# Import excel file with bad column order

Tags: excel, ssis

I've to import a file (probably .csv or .txt) via a SSIS-package.
The problem is, that the file is an excel file at the moment and is written very human readable which means it looks something like this:

> Name1; ColumnName1; Data; Data; Data;...
>
> Name1; ColumnName2; Data; Data; Data;...
>
> Name1; ColumnName3; Data; Data; Data;...
>
> Name2; ColumnName1; Data; Data; Data;...
>
> Name2; ColumnName2; Data; Data; Data;...

The thing is that I need a database compatible order for the import.
I did try to import everything in a dummy table with columns like Value0, Value1, Value3,... just as the file looks like at the moment and then dynamically create a new Table with the column names which are the values contained in Value1 of my dummy table. But how can I insert the values in the right column? And also I don't think that this is a good way to import files... (I hope you understand what I mean)

Does anyone have any idea how to handle these files?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming following structure :

```
col1;col2;col3.....
Name1; ColumnName1; Data; Data; Data;...
```

try to make the table like this:

```
colA:colB:colC
name1:colName1: all values together 
name1:colName2: all values together 
name2:colName1: all values together
name2:colName2: all values together
```

You can get the result like this:

```
SELECT 
    colA, group_concat(colC SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM 
    table 
GROUP BY 
    colA;
```

will give you following result:

```
name1:val1,val2,val3
name2:val1,val2,val3
```

you can then import it using SSIS

Comment: Sounds like a way to go but I got two problems with this... First of all I forgot to say that I'm using a MSSQL Database (means there is no group_concat function) but i think i could work around this. And the second problem is that i have no idea how to get the values together I tried to insert everything but than i get an error that the data is to long ("String or binary data would be truncated.")

Comment: if you have excel you can use concatenate function to merge all values together then either increase the column size in sql or use text column type to insert large amount of data

Comment: okay got around the issue with the to long data (sometimes I'm a little bit stupid... I set the datatype to varchar(50) :D)...

Comment: Thanks a lot I almost got it like i want it but the big first step is done your answer was the key!